# ZSH function not working with a "Missing end of string" error

Tags: error-handling, zsh

I'm teaching myself to write zsh functions and I'm stumped right away with a string error I don't understand. I have this function:

```
function copyToDrafts() {
  print($1)
}
```

in my command line editor (Terminal) I type:

```
copyToDrafts "test"
```

and receive this error:

```
copyToDrafts:1: missing end of string
```

I couldn't find any explanation on the error message and can't see anything wrong with what I am passing, though obviously something is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Drop the parentheses: `print $1`.

Comment: Thanks, make it an answer so I can give you a bump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parentheses are not part of the syntax; they are interpreted as introducing a glob qualifier on the pattern `print`. After parameter expansion, the pattern to be evaluated is

```
print(test)
```

with the following glob qualifiers:

1. `t` - match files named `print` that have their sticky bits set
2. `e` execute a shell command. `s` acts as the delimiter, but there is no "closing" `s`, which produces the observed error.

You simply need to drop the parentheses.

```
copyToDrafts () {
  print $1
}
```